# What plant does Noel use as an umbrella/parasol?

Tags: sora-no-method

There is a scene in the opening (and several others througout the anime) where Noel is using a huge leaf as a sort of umbrella or parasol.

Is that plant a real one? What plant is that?

[image: That's one BIG mothertrucking leaf!]

Comment: Maybe adding an image of this could be a good idea. ;)

Comment: @JNat I blame crunchyroll DRM for the lack of one. But krazek to the rescue.

Comment: I'm quite sure the anime doesn't say anything to answer this, but the town is modeled after [Tōyako, Hokkaido](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C5%8Dyako,_Hokkaido), and Noel can't leave town, so perhaps looking into the indigenous plants would provide an answer. However, the flora in the area are pretty diverse (the area is a national park) so it isn't such an easy task.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen the anime, but I know of a couple big-leaved plants that grow in Japan. Here are three genera with links to Google’s image search:

- [*Farfugium* sp.](http://www.google.com/search?q=farfugium%20japan&tbm=isch) (ツワブキ tsuwabuki), especially [*F. japonicum*](http://www.google.com/search?q=farfugium%20japonicum%20japan&tbm=isch)
- [*Hosta* sp.](http://www.google.com/search?q=hosta%20japan&tbm=isch) (ギボウシ gibōshi), several big-leaved species native to Japan
- [*Petasites* sp.](http://www.google.com/search?q=petasites%20japan&tbm=isch) (フキ fuki), especially [*P. japonicum*](http://www.google.com/search?q=petasites%20japonicum%20japan&tbm=isch)

And then—of course—there exist many more species with big leaves similar to the one depicted in the question. It all comes down to whether the designer based the ‘umbrella’ on real-life plants or just relied on our perceived perception of an umbrella-like plant.